# Monoose DeprecationWarning collection.ensureIndex and useNewUrlParser

Tags: mongodb, performance

If you facing problem in mongoose while creating connection with following two warning:
1. DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureIndex is deprecated. Use createIndexes instead.
2. DeprecationWarning: useNewUrlParser: true

Then you can use use following two line of code to avoid this issue:

```
mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser',true);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex',true);
mongoose.connect(dbURI)
.then(connection => {
  console.log('Connected to MongoDB DB')
})
.catch(error => {
console.log(error.message)
})
```

Comment: Or you can just use an additional object as the second argument of mongoose.connect function example mongoose.connect(dbUri, {useUnifiedTopology: true, useCreateIndex: true, useNewUrlParser: true});